# TxPower always 127 with Android Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I implement a Android app to measure the distance between two android Bluetooth devices based on the rssi and txPower attribute. But the txPower attribute is always 127 no matter how far away the devices are.

```
result.getTxPower()  --> always 127
```

Advertise Configuration:

```
AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setConnectable(false)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .build();

    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .addManufacturerData(0x004c, md)
            .build();

    getBluetoothLeAdvertiser().startAdvertising(settings, data, advertiseCallback());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TX_POWER_NOT_PRESENT:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult#TX_POWER_NOT_PRESENT

Comment: What can be the issue that de value is not present?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this TX always 127?

Comment: For starters, your `AdvertiseData.Builder` also needs a `setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true)`. But even doin so, it still doesn't work for me. Still getting 127. Have you found any solution?

Comment: No solutions yet?